# Multiple hovering elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

having a bit of an issue. I have a set of 3 white elements that when I hover over any of them, all of them turn blue. I have my javascript for one of the objects here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".dl").hover(function (g) {
        $(".pdfasdf").show();
    },
    function (g) {
        $(".pdfasdf").hide();
    });
});
```

But I'm unsure of how to incorporate the other two into the code. There's also a weird jumping issue with this current one but I'm sure that's just my css..

If there's an easier way to make all 3 of them blue then any suggestions would be appreciated! I'm having a lot of issues with the blue effects due to the element:hover in my css not working in jq...

[my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZEyKM/)

Comment: can you create a fiddle? It is hard to guess what might be wrong

Comment: sorry I updated with the jsfiddle! thank you!

Comment: I don't know which elements you want to target but you can use `.siblings('selector')` to get all siblings and then show/hide them at will.

Comment: You want to establish a coherent relationship between the elements you wish to interact with. If you have, say, 3 blocks, each one of them that shows a different block, then ensure the blocks are created in equal order, then just simply use `$('ele').eq($(this).index()).show/hide()`. Or use data attributes, so many ways to develop relationships.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrapped an element around you links, set `visibility: hidden;` and then on hover, all child links are `visibility: visible;`.

I think this is what you meant, but I could be mistaken.
http://jsfiddle.net/ZEyKM/5/

`display: none;` won't render an element so you cant possibly trigger a hover on it.

Hope this sets you in the right direction. In general I avoid inline style attributes and using jQuery to change appearance in a way that doesn't use classes.

Good luck!